# How to open a system settings activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to open this class on the click of a button, it works fine, however, this class is not present in HTC devices, so i want my app to show a toast on this exception, but it doesn't show anything-

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL");
        if ((intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "you are offline", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// No equalizer found :(
        }
```

Comment: If your class is an activity, try using `this` instead of `getBaseContext()`.

Comment: that is not the issue... i tried opening another activity, it just doesn't get called

Answer (score 0):

You can open with

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

You can return by pressing back button on device.

Comment: where should i put this line?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

In your **MainActivity.java** put

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL");
        if ((intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)) {
            // here is the changes  
            // REQUEST_CODE is an any integer value
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unable to open setting..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

**If you want to handle result of an intent then**

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // add your code here
    }
```

Comment: can i use  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: Yes, any integer no allowed